# How to quicksort this data (step by step) with my own chosen pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have data (3 is the pivot):

281374

i move two pointers from left and right

first i have 2 and 4 so i swap nothing

then i have 8 and 7 so i swap and have:

273184

now i have pinter in 3 and 1 so I swap:

271384

now left pointer = rightpointer - 1 so i should quick sort these:

271 | 384

separately right?

but if i do i will get something like this:

127 | 348

and this is NOT SORTED data!

what I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

> then i have 8 and 7 so i swap and have:
>
> 273184

you do not swap these values. Everything from the left greater than the pivot got to be placed on the right, everything on the right lower than the pivot has to be placed on the left. But 7 and 8 are both GREATER than the pivot element.

see people dancing the quicksort algorithm:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't swap corresponding numbers if the left is greater than the right, you would swap them depending on how they compare to the *pivot value*.  `7` is greater than the pivot value already, so it's already on the correct (right) side of the pivot.

However, the standard algorithm for in-place partitioning is fairly different from what you seem to be attempting. Take a look at the [Wikipedia article for in-place Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version).

Answer (score 0):

QuickSort doesn't work that way

if 3 is your pivot:

swap your pivot (3), with the end

```
281374 -> 281473

281473
-
```

is 2 less than 3? yes, but its already on the left so leave it alone

```
281473
 -
```

is 8 less than 3? no, so we need to figure out the next correct place to put it.
Walk down the list and the first item <= the pivot (it can be the pivot itself) we swap.
In this case, its a `1` so....

```
281473 -> 218473
```

now we're at

```
218473
  -
```

repeat til sorted.

Comment: Normally, the part you suggest at "walk down the list" is pretty inefficient since it represents a nested loop.  It would be very bad in the worse-case scenario.  It's easier to just leave `8` alone (or swap it with itself) and record index `1` as the index to swap with the next time you find a small number (in this case, `1`).

Comment: @MarkPeters I'm not worried about optimization at this point. I think it's more important the OP understands how Quicksort works. After that he should worry about performance. "Premature optimation", "root of all evil", all that jazz ;)

Comment: It's not premature optimization when you've already decided you're using quicksort :-).  You choose quicksort because its algorithmic complexity is lower than other algorithms.  But its complexity of `O(n log n)` is entirely dependent on a partition algorithm that is `O(n)`.  Yours isn't.  So really choosing quicksort at all would be the premature optimization, since your complexity isn't an improvement on simpler algorithms.

Comment: @MarkPeters from a practical standpoint, I'd say you're entirely correct. But again, I just want the OP to understand how Quicksort works since its apparently they didn't understand the concept at all and this way is the best first step in understanding how it works. I do admit though that I could be biased on "the best way" since this is how I learned it

Answer (score 0):

3 is pivot then check 2:2 is less than 3 so do nothing
8 is greater than pivot so it moves to end of array
1 is less than 3 :do nothing
and other elements are greater than 3 and in their correct place
now we have:213748
now we take this array apart to two sub arrays and get first elements of them pivot and sort them with quick sort
123748
123478
hip hip hurray
we sort it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider breaking your answer up -- it's hard to follow because it all runs into one sentence.